# How to build OpenSSL for WP8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, openssl, runtime, winsock

How to build OpenSSL for WP8?

AFAIK, we must replace `winsock.h` by `winsock2.h` because WP8 only supports `winsock2.h`. And maybe we must replaces code to target WinRT architecture on WP8 (ThreadPool, ...)

The caveat is that we must build OpenSSL as WP8 static library, so that the output lib can be wrapped by WP8 runtime component, right ?

Comment: With Visual Studio 2013 Update 3, Microsoft has enabled WinSock and OpenSSL for Windows Phone and Windows Store apps. You can use WinSock APIs and hence many popular OSS libraries such as libcURL, libwebsockets, OpenSSL etc.
More about it here - http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/10/13/winsock-and-more-open-source-for-your-windows-store-apps/

Comment: also check this out - https://github.com/Microsoft/openssl/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is what you have to do, go to [this link](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=0f330bb90c07a36e&id=F330BB90C07A36E!241) and download the VSbuild, now put that into the source files downloaded from the OpenSSL website, the folder structure should look like this:

> ```
>   apps
>   bugs
>   certs
>   .....
>   vsbuild
> ```

once that is done, open the solution, it should upgrade it to VS12, change the settings to a Windows Phone RT build, to generate DLL's there is no need to build *_lib*, so change the other projects, most changes you need to do are to libeay32, **do not** compile *openssl* project, just ignore that, start by building **libeay32**, and start making changes to the code, as there are some functions we don't have in WinRT, you can either `#ifdef` them out, or create your own functions,

**NOTE** for `rand_win.c` change the functions to use `rand_s` and `#ifdef` most of the code there is, this might muck up the security, you will have to test it out yourself

Good Luck !

Comment: Yep this works - its a bit of a headache, but it works.
You may want to add an empty getenv() function somewhere, and I made up the following RAND_poll replacement function - no idea if it is well done or not, so don't just copy it without a little investigation first:
`int RAND_poll(void)
{
 int i;
 unsigned char v;
 for (i=0; i<(ENTROPY_NEEDED*4); i++)
 {
  v = (unsigned char) (rand() % 256);
  RAND_add (&v, sizeof v, 1);
  v = 0;
 }
 return 1;
 }
`
Also the two *_lib projects were enough no need to use the other 3 projects at all that come in the sln.

Comment: Oh, and I needed to define _WIN32_WINNT=_WIN32_WINNT_WIN8 to get things to compile also.

Comment: I followed these steps and getting FileNotFoundException dependency issue when creating  new instance of NativeCrypto in WP8 Project.Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Microsoft openssl fork on github with support for windows phone 8.1/8.0 and Windows Store 8.1, that address the entropy on each platform using windows random generators, instructions are located at INSTALL.WINAPP, there is a script located at

ms\do_vsprojects.bat

you should be able to just execute that script withing the root location and open vsout\openssl.sln to build the openssl libraries for different windows platforms.

The fork is located at

https://github.com/microsoft/openssl

At this momment these changes are being in process to be integrated with the main OpenSSL source code base.

Comment: Great news, now we can use this solution

Answer (score 1):

This is so that if anyone wants to build the new version of **OpenSSL "1.0.1g"** that fixes the **Heartbleed** problem you can follow the previous steps whit the following changes:

I renamed the folder **include** to **--include** and create a new folder named include, the VS project will take care of copying the information, **--include**  if you like you can remove this, when i build the project without this change there where compilation issues.

**Note**: the include folder that i changed is the one found in the root not the one found under ***VSbuild***

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Here is a download of pre-compiled OpenSSL libraries for Windows Phone 8.1 among other platforms:

https://www.teskalabs.com/blog/openssl-binary-distribution-for-developers-static-library

*Disclaimer: I run that site.*