# _WIN32_WINNT for Windows Phone 8 (Force Include versus define)?

Tags: windows-phone-8, cross-compiling, command-prompt

TLDR: question is at the bottom.

I'm trying to compile a library from the command line for Windows Phone 8. I have all the hardware and software in place. As a test, I was successful in creating a test library from a Visual Studio solution.

When I attempt to compile the file from the command line, I get the following. The environment was set using Visual Studio's "ARM Phone Tools Command Prompt".

```
C:\Users\Jeffrey Walton\Desktop\openssl-fips-2.0.5>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Micro
soft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\WPSDK\WP80\bin\x86_arm\CL.exe" -DFIPS_START -Iinc32 -
Itmp32dll -DOPENSSL_FIPSCANISTER -DOPENSSL_THREADS -DDSO_WIN32 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_
DEPRECATE /AI"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.0\Windows Metadata" /D
_USRDLL /D NDEBUG /D _WINDLL /D WINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_FAMILY_PHONE_APP /fp:precis
e -DOPENSSL_USE_APPLINK -I. -DOPENSSL_NO_RC5 -DOPENSSL_NO_MD2 -DOPENSSL_NO_KRB5
-DOPENSSL_FIPS -DOPENSSL_NO_JPAKE -DOPENS -DSSL_NO_STATIC_ENGINE -c .\fips\fips_
canister.c

fips_canister.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.0\include\ws2tcpip.h(1032) : fatal e
rror C1083: Cannot open include file: 'wspiapi.h': No such file or directory
```

I could not find `wspiapi.h` in either the Visual Studio install directory nor the Phone Kit directory. When I check `ws2tcpip.h`, I see this piece of goodness:

```
// Unless the build environment is explicitly targeting only
// platforms that include built-in getaddrinfo() support, include
// the backwards-compatibility version of the relevant APIs.
//
#if !defined(_WIN32_WINNT) || (_WIN32_WINNT <= 0x0500)
#include <wspiapi.h>
#endif
```

In `ws2tcpip.h`, it looks like most of the conditional compilation is occurring around `_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600`.

When I check `<winsdkver.h>`, I see the following (but no define for Windows Phone 8):

```
// _WIN32_WINNT version constants
//
...
#define _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA                  0x0600
#define _WIN32_WINNT_WS08                   0x0600
#define _WIN32_WINNT_LONGHORN               0x0600
#define _WIN32_WINNT_WIN7                   0x0601
#define _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8                   0x0602
```

My question: should I force the include of `<winsdkver.h>` with `/FI` (or some other header to set the version); or should I define `_WIN32_WINNT` to `_WIN32_WINNT_WIN8`? I know the force include works. (For what its worth, Visual Studio is not suffering the same, and its not doing anything special with some of these defines).

Answer (score 1):

I defined `_WIN32_WINNT=_WIN32_WINNT_WIN8` as you suggested when [building the OpenSSL library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203985/how-to-build-openssl-for-wp8) for Windows Phone 8 in Visual Studio - it seems to work/run fine on both the emulator (Win32) and the device (ARM). Not sure if this answers your question or not, but at least it gives you some more info.