# How do I build openssl for windows phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, openssl, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

#### Question

My target is to build openssl library for Windows Phone 8.1 via `VS2015`

I was trying to build from [Microsoft OpenSSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/openssl) but failed.

The error I got:

```
D:\dependency\ms_openssl>nmake -f ms\nt.mak

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 12.00.21005.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Building OpenSSL

    # building source code ... <ignore>

    link /dll /EXPORT:winrt_main /nologo /subsystem:console /opt:ref "WindowsPhoneCore.lib" "RuntimeObject.lib" "PhoneAppModelHost.lib" /NODEFAULTLIB:"kernel32.lib" /NODEFAULTLIB:"ole32.lib" /APPCONTAINER /debug /out:out32\constant_time_test.dll @C:\Users\litian\AppData\Local\Temp\nm8800.tmp
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'WindowsPhoneCore.lib'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\amd64\link.EXE"' : return code '0x49d'
Stop.
```

#### Description

My Steps:

1. open `VS2015 x64 ARM Cross Tools Command Prompt`
2. Navigate to openssl source code, and run the following lines,

   ```
   >perl Configure no-asm no-hw no-dso VC-WINPHONE
   >ms\do_winphone
   >nmake -f ms\nt.mak
   ```

and then I got the error. **How do I link the missing libraries?**

#### More details

I tried to build from openssl official website, but it doesn't support to build windows phone, only for windows x86 and x64 architectures.

#### Edit

(1) @jwww
as for [how to build openssl  for wp8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203985/how-to-build-openssl-for-wp8), my question is different as I was trying to build from Microsoft openssl support. And for the method the link mentioned I have tried but failed.

Both the link and Microsoft OpenSSL are using VS2013, however, I am using VS2015. As a part of development environment, I just put into the title which you removed ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build OpenSSL for WP8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203985/how-to-build-openssl-for-wp8)

Comment: It looks like you need to install the Windows Phone SDK. Just [bikeshedding](http://bikeshed.com/), but OpenSSL is so crippled its not really worth the effort. The problem is with the Windows Phone APIs, and its even worse on Windows RT.

Comment: @jww, before I post the thread, I have followed the link you mentioned, however, it hasn't worked for me so far. And I have already installed wp 8.1 and wp10 sdk.  I need build current C library into WP which has openssl functions, so I have no choice ;)